# php - add class:active to div depending on querystring

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the css of a div based on the currant queystring of the page, the purpose is to show which link is currently active in the left menu.

The format of the URL will be WWW.mysite.co.uk/Folder/Folder2/Page.php?id=1

HTML

```
    <div id="Left-Menu">

    <div id="Left-Menu-Title"><p id="Left-Menu-Title-Text">Title</p>
    </div>

    <a href="?id=1"><div class="Left-Menu-Button">
    <p class="Left-Menu-Button-Text" >Button1</p>
    </div></a>        

    <a href="?id=2"><div class="Left-Menu-Button">
    <p class="Left-Menu-Button-Text" >Button2</p>
    </div></a>

    <a href="?id=3"><div class="Left-Menu-Button">
    <p class="Left-Menu-Button-Text" >Button3</p>
    </div></a>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
    #Left-Menu-Title{
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
    }

    #Left-Menu-Title-Text{
padding-left:8px;
font-size:0.85em;
font-family:segoe UI;
line-height:16px;
color:#5b0400;
    }

   .Left-Menu-Button{
width:69px;
height:20px;
margin-bottom:5px;
    }

    p.Left-Menu-Button-Text{
padding-left:8px;
padding-top:1px;
font-size:0.95em;
font-family:segoe UI;
color:#a61407;
    }

    .Left-Menu-Button:hover{
background-color:#a61407;
opacity:0.6;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    }

    .Left-Menu-Button:hover p.Left-Menu-Button-Text, .Left-Menu-Button.hover p.Left-Menu-Button-Text {
display: block;
color:#ffffff;
    }

    .active{
width:69px;
height:20px;
margin-bottom:5px;
background-color:#a61407;
    }

    p.active{
padding-left:8px;
padding-top:1px;
font-size:0.95em;
font-family:segoe UI;
color:#ffffff;
    }

    a{
text-decoration:none;
    }
```

How do I add the Class:active to the Left-Menu-Button and Left-Menu-Button-Text when the href = the same id as the querystring.

I believe you could add the class:active to the a tag by doing this:

```
    <a href="?id=1" <?php
    if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == "?id=1")
   {
    echo ' class="active" ';
   }
   ?>
   ><div class="Left-Menu-Button">
    <p class="Left-Menu-Button-Text" >Button1</p>
    </div></a>
```

But is it possible to echo the Left-Menu-Button and Left-Menu-Button-Text div's instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHPs [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable.

```
<a href="?id=1" <?php if ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) && $_GET['id'] == 1 ) echo 'class="active"' ?>>
    <div class="Left-Menu-Button">
    <p class="Left-Menu-Button-Text" >Button1</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Or add it to the class attribute so that other classes can be added.

```
<a href="?id=1" class="<?php if ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) && $_GET['id'] == 1 ) echo "active " ?>new_class">
    <div class="Left-Menu-Button">
    <p class="Left-Menu-Button-Text" >Button1</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Just make sure to change the id value `== 1` per element.

`isset()` is used so that you're not checking against an undefined variable if the page url scheme doesn't have `id` as a query string.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone would downvote this answer when it's a working solution without cruft and wildly bad markup like the other "answers".

Comment: This looks like the right answer, assuming my interpretation of the question is correct. That being said, maybe he wants to also add "active" to the "Left-Menu-Button-Text" paragraph. There is a p.active class in the stylesheet posted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along the lines of

```
<?php 
$classActive = NULL;
if($_GET["id"] == 1){
    $classActive = " active";
}
?>
<a href="?id=1">
    <div class="Left-Menu-Button<?php echo $classActive; ?>">
        <p class="Left-Menu-Button-Text<?php echo $classActive; ?>" >Button1</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right this code should do it. I believe you are trying to make a link active if that is the current page you are on. Just add this code inside your class "".

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']) AND $_GET['id'] == 1)
   {
    echo ' active';
   }
?>
```

Comment: doesn't work to echo in location that OP is doing it...will just add that as text between html tags

Comment: isn't that what he wants, is the class text to show up in between html tags

Comment: ok I see that now, he already has a class set and he wants to add to it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$id = false;
if(isset($_GET['id']){
   $id = $_GET['id'];
}

?>
```

## html...

```
<?php if($id == '1'): ?>
  <a href="?id=1" class="active">
<?php else: ?>
  <a href="?id=1">
<?php endif; ?>
```